# DisplayMemberPath isn't displaying correctly with WPFToolkit controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using **Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition** controls. When I bind a list of dynamic objects to some of their controls like `CheckComboBox` and set `DisplayMemberPath` to a specific property, it doesn't display that property in textbox of the control but the full dynamic object.

Example: [CheckComboBox textbox area doesn't show Name property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBXHK.jpg)

XAML:

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox x:Name="BooksComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

Code-behind:

```
BooksComboBox.ItemsSource = Database.GetBooks();
```

The dropdown displays Name property correctly but the textbox area displays the full dynamic object.
What can be the workaround to make textbox area to display Name property of selected items?

Comment: it's seems like your DisplayMemberpath and ItemSource doesn't in sync mode why don't you bind the Combobox in xaml

Comment: @DhavalPatel Do you mean setting ItemsSource in XAML instead? I need to set ItemsSource at run time and they're not static. That's why I set in code-behind. But I don't think that could be the cause. I did the same to native WPF controls like common ComboBox and it displayed member path correctly.